# How do I work with Runtime Virtual Textures in UE5?

Tags: unreal, unreal-5

I just created a Runtime Virtual Texture, but when I double click to edit it, I get no options at all.

How can I reach the options and work with it, what am I missing here?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

So, I just needed to press Window => Details and it opened the options back up. Not really sure what happened there (if I accidentally closed it or not).